# How to push/deploy project on digital ocean without git clone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, bitbucket, digital-ocean

I have a droplet on `digtalocean` . I am deploying my rails app on it. I know all steps and done that on droplet. Next step is to take clone on it meanz push project to digitalocean. Is it possible to push project on remote without taking any clone or using `bitbucket`,`github` etc.

If yes then how?

Comment: So you don't want to use git for this? (a better way to do a git clone from the server would be to use git-deploy see: https://github.com/mislav/git-deploy) If you don't want to use git at all, you may want to use `scp`? Am I missing something?

Comment: Any other way except scp?

Comment: Did you look into `git-deploy`? It's a really good way to deploy your application. You can also boot a ftp server and access it with ftp if you want that.

Comment: Why must you not use `git clone`? That answer may help us suggest appropriate solutions.

Comment: @Chris bcz client doesnt have any git account and he doesnt want to push code there

Comment: @HaseebAhmad, do you mean the client doesn't have a Git​​_Hub_ account? Git and GitHub are different things. It's perfectly possible to use Git without GitHub. Are you using any version control software at all right now?